# Test if a Sidekiq job has been created when using .delay

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, redis, sidekiq

I'm using Rails 4.2 with sidekiq 4.1. I want to test that I'm actually queuing a user for deletion. Right now I'm doing something like this in the code

```
User.delay.destroy(user_id)
```

and I'm used to test it like so

```
it { expect(UserRemoveWorker.jobs.size).to eq 1 }
```

but I don't have a worker like that and I don't want to create a new worker (the `UserRemoveWorker` in this case) when I can simply call the `delay` method.

What's the best way to see if I have queued the job / written it to Redis?

Thanks!

Comment: Mike Perham is the creator of Sidekiq, better use his answer and not mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
assert_equal 1, Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedClass.jobs.size
```

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing#testing-delay-and-delay_for-methods